# Set size limit for request param

Tags: java, spring, rest

Currently I have an API like this:

```
    @GetMapping(/user/{id})
    public ResponseEntity<MyClass> getById(@PathVariable @Max(value = Long.MAX_VALUE, message= ID_LENGTH_EXCEED_MESSAGE) Long id) {
      //some code here 
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The issue is when I consume the API like this:

```
    {baseUrl}/user/1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

I get an error message like this:

```
    Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; 
    nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 
    "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

Do you have any idea how to restrict the length of the value in path variable or even in request param and get a custom restricted message?

Comment: just think, if you can write like `long l = 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111L;` in Java, if you can, you can do above also, since before you throw custom exception, library already throwing an exception while fitting long value,

Comment: Please use Long varible to handle this issue.integer cannot support large number of data

Comment: @dkb Yeah I understand that but what I am expecting is to restrict the size or max value in the controller itself.

Comment: @BathriNathan I have used the Long there

Comment: @SudipBolakhe please check my answer it will be helpful to you...

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11041, this feature is in queue to be implemented but there are some workaround, still issue will persist because Long id has to hold value first before validation works on it, so either you change to String and do validation or have custom exception handler.

Comment: @dkb Yeah I too figure out  that, If we need to apply size constraints or  max value, first the value needs to be within the range of the data type.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the input param(id) of that rest Service method from `Long` to `String`

   then check String length and do you validation here
2. Then convert that String value to long as below:

   `Long idValue = Long.valueOf(Id);`
   now add your existing code here

Answer (score 1):

It seems java cant handle too large number as int or long so handle as string and use length property of string to handle and parse into int or long.

**Note:**
if length of the string is too long than integer or long can support then use return function or any call back function.

Java variable range:-

[image]

Comment: Does it mean that the value we send as id must be between -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 so that we can apply the @Max

Comment: @SudipBolakhe  yes definitely it is the limit for the variable check it for integer i will work. as u expected

Answer (score 1):

```
@RestController
public class YourController {

    @GetMapping("/yourEndpoint")
    public ResponseEntity<?> yourEndpoint(
        @RequestParam @Size(max = 50, message = "Parameter 'param' should be at most 50 characters long.") String param
    ) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api) is described how to throw custom errors. I would suggest to accept an `String` as `value` for the user id. When the parsing of the `value` fails, you can throw your custom error.

Comment: Sounds helpful. But is there any way to restrict the size or max value in the controller itself.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know any other way to do this.